# Read key from values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

I am working creating virtual service with helm
my goal is to create vs that accept single or multiple match block with help of helm
right now I am stuck at very last part , I want to read httpmatch uri dynamically
for eg values.yaml (apologies for bad indentation in yaml not able to input format in this editor)

values.yaml

```yaml
  paths: 
   - uri: 
      - "/process-devlopment/projects"
      - "/process-devlopment/modules"
     rewrite: "/process-devlopment/projects"
     servicePort: 80 
     method: "POST" 
   - uri: 
      exact: "/process-devlopment/projects"
     rewrite: "/process-devlopment/modules"
```

code from vs.yaml

```yaml
   {{- range $key, $value := $path }}
  - match:
    - uri:
       "{{- toYaml $key.uri }}": "{{- toYaml  $value.uri }}"
    rewrite:
       uri: "{{- toYaml $value.rewrite }}"
```

Here I want to get prefix/exact/regex under URI from values.yaml
but it appears keys are not read in helm I can only get values by iterating through loop using range block
can anyone help me to get key from values.yaml dynamically
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: Would you please reformat the code? It is hard to be understood.

Comment: thanks for response @andromeda I have format the code 
I am looking for this particular line
    - uri:
       "{{- toYaml $key.uri }}": "{{- toYaml  $value.uri }}"

Here I want to get "{{- toYaml $key.uri }}" dynamically from values.yaml
eg. prefix: /foo
      exact: /foo/bar

Comment: How desired rendered `vs.yaml` would be like?

Comment: this is ingress from values.yaml
```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  host: "foo.bar"
  gateway: "foo"
  paths: 
   - uri: 
      - "/process-devlopment/projects"
      - "/process-devlopment/modules"
     rewrite: "/process-devlopment/projects"
     servicePort: 80 
     method: "POST" 
   - uri: 
      exact: "/process-devlopment/projects"
     rewrite: "/process-devlopment/modules"
```
method and post are option but I need to have multiple match block under virtual service.

Comment: Desired VS
```yaml
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /products
        - uri:
            exact: /products/
          method:
            exact: GET
      route:
        - destination:
            host: productpage
            port:
              number: 9080
      rewrite:
        uri: /api/v1/products
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /process-devlopment/modules
      route:
        - destination:
            host: productpage
            port:
              number: 9080
      rewrite:
        uri: /productpage
```

Comment: Add to the question please, hard to read this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make out what the key and value of your $path will be.
Anyway, If you need to get the content of key and value, I'd restructure the list as followed

assumed original list:

```
paths:
  - exact: "uri1"
  - prefix: "uri2"
```

updated list:

```
paths: 
   - pattern: prefix
     path: "uri2"
   - pattern: exact
     path: "uri1"
     ...
```

The virtual-service.yaml could then be:

```
{{- range $.Values.paths }}   
  - match:
    - uri:
       "{{ .pattern }}": "{{ .path }}"
    rewrite:
       uri: "{{ .path }}" 
{{- end }}
```

---

In comments, the poster asks how would it look if there were multiple uri's for the pattern. This is untested code, however should give you the idea, This is how I'd restructure it

Values.yaml

```
paths: 
   - pattern: prefix
     uris:
      - "uri1"
      - "uri2"
   - pattern: exact
     uris:
      - "uri3"
      - "uri4"
```

Now, since we'll need pattern while iterating through uris, you have to assign it to something. Then you can iterate over the uris like,

virtual-service.yaml:

```
{{- range $.Values.paths }}
  {{- $pattern := .pattern }} 
  {{- range .uris }}   
    - match:
      - uri:
         "{{ $pattern }}": "{{ . }}"
      rewrite:
        uri: "{{ . }}" 
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: @Andromeda you are magician, it worked 
Just another question on this, how to handle multiple path in values.yaml with same pattern

for eg
paths: 
   - pattern: prefix
     path: "uri2"
     path: uri3

Comment: @ameykambli have updated the answer with the additional requirement